# Optmise if else Condition javaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript method. It's converting/mapping integer values to string days. How can I improve this code into something more efficient? Any idea?

```
private _convertIntToStringDays(days: any){
        let dayArray: any = [];
        for (let day in days){
            if (days[day] == 1){
                dayArray.push('monday');
            }
            else if (days[day] == 2){
                dayArray.push('tuesday');
            }
            else if (days[day] == 3){
                dayArray.push('wednesday');
            }
            else if (days[day] == 4){
                dayArray.push('thursday');
            }
            else if (days[day] == 5){
                dayArray.push('friday');
            }
            else if (days[day] == 6){
                dayArray.push('saturday');
            }
            else if (days[day] == 0){
                dayArray.push('sunday');
            }
        }
        dayArray.shift(dayArray[0]);
        console.log(dayArray);
        return dayArray;
    }
```

Comment: Looks more like TypeScript or Flow to me...

Comment: sorry its TypeScript

Comment: The days am getting is integer values

Comment: why are you intentionally duplicating the first item in the array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save name of days in the array and index it with your variable

```
private _convertIntToStringDays(days: any) {
        let dayArray: any = [];
        let dayNames = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];
        for (let day in days){
            dayArray.push(dayNames[days[day]]);
        }
        dayArray.shift(dayArray[0]);
        console.log(dayArray);
        return dayArray;
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak agree with you, but I provided an example only with necessary changes against the original code

Answer (score 4):

Use array...

```
function dayNumberToString(dayNumber) {
    return ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'][dayNumber % 7]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a lookup table:

```
const dayNames = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", .... ]
console.log(dayNames[1]) // gives you Monday

[1,0,2].map(x => dayNames[x])  // converts an array of day numbers
```

Comment: rather `dayNames[days[day]]`

Comment: The OP's function expects an array and returns an array with matches

Comment: @haim770 this answer has more than enough information to solve the problem without spoon feeding it to the OP

Comment: @Alnitak, The actual mapping is the crucial part (although generally trivial, using `map()`), I wouldn't consider it spoon-feeding. And seems like @Thilo eventually agrees.

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what [TypeScript enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)s are for.

```
// outside the class
enum Day { sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };

class Foo {
  private _convertIntToStringDays(days: number[]) {
    return days.map(day => Day[day]);
  }
}
```

For reference, TS transpiles the enum into the following, allowing bi-directional lookup:

```
var Day;
(function (Day) {
    Day[Day["sunday"] = 0] = "sunday";
    Day[Day["monday"] = 1] = "monday";
    Day[Day["tuesday"] = 2] = "tuesday";
    Day[Day["wednesday"] = 3] = "wednesday";
    Day[Day["thursday"] = 4] = "thursday";
    Day[Day["friday"] = 5] = "friday";
    Day[Day["saturday"] = 6] = "saturday";
})(Day || (Day = {}));
```